# Hive SQL escape special char

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive SQL. I  want to query some data which contains this part:

```
aid\":\"abcd
```

I have tried  this:

```
data like '%aid\\\\":\\\\"abcd%'
```

but it does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try this ?

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'aid\\":\\"abcd' str
)
SELECT str FROM data WHERE str LIKE '%aid\\":\\"abcd%';
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jaytiger! Looks like we do not need to escape the \ in hive SQL?

Comment: yes, you don't need to escape the escape character(\) again. `'aid\\\\":\\\\"abcd'` actually means a string literal `'aid\\":\\"abcd'` which you don't intend.